# How to set resource limits for services started by systemd upon bootup

Tags: systemd, services, ulimit

I understand that `ulimit` is a `bash` builtin that allows us to change resource limits for a shell and the children spawned from that shell. For limit changes applicable to all logged in users I believe we make changes to `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

However say I have an `httpd` service started by `systemd` upon bootup and I want to change resource limits for this service. Will this be done via `systemd` or is there any other mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

The man page for [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) lists many settings that can be set in the `[Service]` part of a Unit such as `httpd` to limit the resources available to its processes, for example `LimitCPU=, LimitFSIZE=, LimitDATA=, LimitSTACK=`, which correspond to `ulimit -t`, `-f`, `-d`, `-s`.